# Pemission denied when trying to create a directory

Tags: command-line

```
[SHARAD@localhost ~]$ cd /var/www/html
[SHARAD@localhost html]$ mkdir sharad
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘sharad’: Permission denied
[SHARAD@localhost html]$
```

Comment: Please show us the output of `id` as well as `ls -la /var/www/html`.

Comment: `ls -ld /var/www/html` would help figuring out why, in addition to output from `id`

Answer (score 1):

Guarantee that your user is a apache server administrator. As root or with sudo do:

```
#adduser SHARAD www-data 

#chgrp www-data -R /var/www

#chmod g+rw /var/www -R
```

All new files you created can be change to the group www-data now, as the normal user SHARAD:

```
[ SHARAD@localhost html ] $ chgrp www-data -R mynewfileorfolder
```

And when necessary you can give the folder or file the right permission

```
[ SHARAD@localhost html ] $ chmod g+rw -R mynewfileorfolder
```

**Very important:** www-data group varies depending on your distro, in some is apache, apache2, or httpd. Please check your /var/www folder with ls -l to find out!

That's it.